# How to create a method in Python

Tags: django, python-2.7

How to create a method in python which takes dictionary and parameter to find in dictionary as arguments and returns a value

Comment: What's wrong with `dict.get()`?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a function that will take a dictionary and a key as parameters and will return the value associated with that key?

Comment: don't bother defining your own method just use dict.get() as @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams suggests.

Comment: this is actually to parse the JSON request.the request is converted to dictionary and retireve values from it by passing a param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python class `dict` has a method `get`

```
def get(self, key, default=None):
    """Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.

    :type key: T
    :type default: V | None
    :rtype: V
    """
    pass
```

Lets imagine you have smth like this somewhere in your `js`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: someElement.data('url'), // url to your view
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': getCSRFToken()
    },
    data: {
        'var1': selectedId1,
        'var2': selectedId2,
        'var3': selectedId3
    },
    success: function(data) {
       // do smth
    },
    error: function(e) {
        // do smth else
    }
})
```

So in your view you can get it by key from `request.POST`, because `issubclass(type(request.POST), dict) == True`

```
var1 = request.POST.get('var1')
var2 = request.POST.get('var2')
var3 = request.POST.get('var3')
```